# Lost connectionProperties value after loading Spark

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark

First, I config to call `load` table:

```
val s2gathdata = 
    spark.sqlContext
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .options(Map("url" ->"jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@url:1521:orcl",
                 "dbtable" -> "table",
                 "connectionProperties" -> "oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false"))
    .load()
```

It execute successfully. But after that, I call `s2gathdata.count()`, it throws exception missing config `oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectionProperties` should be provided as an argument to `jdbc` call:

```
val properties = new java.util.Properties()
properties.put("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false"

val s2gathdata = 
    spark.sqlContext
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@url:1521:orcl", "table", properties)
```

You can also provide properties encoded in the connection string.

Comment: It works. But can you give me an example about encoded properties in connection string?

Comment: Something similar to this  `jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@url:1521:orcl?oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false`